How can I combine N different ZIO-Streams?
I've been exploring ZIO Streams and ZIO's concurrency model for a while. Recently, I started working on a toy project where I process a large file containing integers. Here's what I've done so far:

Read the file.
Split it into chunks of 10 MB.
Sort each chunk.
Save the sorted chunks to temporary files.

Now, I'm at the next stage: reading all these temporary files into streams, sorting their contents in-memory again, and writing the results to a new file. I'd like to enforce some memory limitations so that I can dive deeper into ZIO's stream framework. You can say I am stuck trying to implement k-way merge, in ZIO.
Here’s the code I have for creating a ZStream from a single file:
private def fileStream(file: Path): Task[Stream[Throwable, Int]] =
  ZIO.succeed {
    ZStream
      .fromPath(file)
      .via(ZPipeline.utf8Decode)
      .via(ZPipeline.splitLines)
      .mapZIO(line =>
        ZIO
          .attempt(line.trim.toInt)
          .orElseFail(new IOException(s"Invalid line in file $file: $line"))
      )
  }

I can create a list of streams using ZIO.foreach:
ZIO.foreach(files)(fileStream)
However, I'm stuck on how to combine multiple ZStreams declaratively. My goal is to merge or combine these streams while respecting some memory constraints.
In theory, I was expecting some sort ofZStream#combine method to merge multiple streams, but I haven’t found a clear solution. How can I achieve this in ZIO Streams?
I tried using ZStream#fromIterable and ZStream#fromIteratorZIO constructors, however these are not combining the effects described (which is reading a line) so I don't think they are doing what I am intending to do.

If you want to pull values from each file no matter the order, you could check ZIO.merge. If it's not the case, could you add some example of the different inputs and the output expected. In the docs of zio streams, there is a page with the operations listed.
